# Java JTable enabled but not editable with a TableCellRenderer and a defaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm using TableCellRenderer to render a button in a cell for a JTable created with Matisse in netbeans.

My problem is ... When a double click on the button, I can reach the text field behind. So I want to set the textfield not editable.

For now, my setEnabled are on true:  table_watchlistMain.setEnabled(true); I need that because I want to user to be eable to select a row ...

I'm using a DefaultTableModel... do I need to make my own model?

**I'm just searching a solution to put the jtable enabled, but not editable. this is possible??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DefaultTableModel.isCellEditable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#isCellEditable-int-int-) method always returns `true`:

> Returns true regardless of parameter values.

So, yes, you should create your own model, for example:

```
public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
{
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```